Amend 2023 Tax Return
I need to amend my 2023 taxes do I need to wait for the refund from the original return to be received before I file an amendment?

There is no such requirement.

Does this answer your question? I need to amend my return but I already received check from IRS with my refund. Should I cash it out now or wait until I amend my return?

Where are you in the world? Tax rules and laws differ.

No, you don't need to wait for ... anything. Just file the amendment. If you owe money, delaying will just increase interest and penalty charges.
